# Creating a list from a csv file, but having problems with built in functions

Tags: python, list

I have a csv file with 124K medians from different samples. I've created a list from the column of choice (F532 Median) and wanted to get the means of the medians, max number, min number. I was able to get the means, but I'm having problems with the max and min. I've tried sorting the list and get the first element for the min, but I get the same error. ('float' object has no attribute 'sort') I've tried converting to strings, but get the same error ,but with string instead of float. I also tried the non-sort approach using a for loop, but same error. Does anyone have a different approach to solve this? Thank you and any help is much appreciated.

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

def process_row(row):
    row["F532 Median"] = float(row["F532 Median"])
    return row

# File located in home directory
file_path = Path.home()/"python_codes"/"253_Slide01_A1.csv"

with file_path.open(mode="r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    row_information = [process_row(row) for row in reader]

t_high = []
count = 0
sum1 = 0

for item in row_information:
    t_high = item["F532 Median"]
    sum1 += t_high
    count += 1
    avg = sum1 / count

sort_list = t_high.sort()

print(sort_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the list `t_high` with the value of `item["F532 Media"]` from each row, so at the end of the loop it will contain the value from the last row. You need to append to the list.

There's no need to recompute the average each time through the loop. Do that at the end. And there's no need to increment `count` in the loop, just use `len(row_information)`

`list.sort()` doesn't return the sorted list, it sorts in place. And if you just want the highest, use `max(t_high)`.

```
for item in row_information:
    high = item["F532 Median"]
    t_high.append(high)
    sum1 += high
    
avg = sum1 / len(row_information)
print(avg, max(t_high))
```